# Why can't I find the Amazon S3 class in the latest version 2.3.5 version of zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the direct download link for zend framework,

https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-2.3.5/ZendFramework-2.3.5.zip

I've downloaded it and across the internet people show tutorials of how to use the amazon s3 class to save files directly to s3. However, I cannot find the amazon s3 class for some reason. Was it recently removed from the zend framework?

Comment: The Amazon libs (and all Zend Service libraries) were never part of ZF2, they are separate packages. The Amazon one is at: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Amazon

Comment: Ok, i downloaded the zend amazon library from that link and tried to use it just like the example shows here, http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html




2015-02-27T17:10:15.212435+00:00 app[web.1]: [27-Feb-2015 17:10:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZendService\Amazon\AbstractAmazon' not found in /app/web/fb/ZendService_Amazon-master/library/ZendService/Amazon/S3/S3.php on line 30

Comment: The docs you linked are for version 1.12 (very old), not for ZF2 - what version are you using? The current docs are http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zendservice.amazon.html

Comment: I just downloaded and tried version 1.12 and even it still gives off a similar error when i try to include the file. I think the problem is that I need a heroku command for updating the composer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using composer?

If you are, you simply need to define the `zendframework/zendservice-amazon` dependency and use `ZendService\Amazon\S3\S3` class to create a new S3 object.